# Use Fluent Validation to maintain input formats, or tweak input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

Is is appropriate to Use Fluent Validation to tweak data?
For example we have a telephone number field, the service layer accepts all formats which Match a certain Regex, all the below are valid formats for the same number:

```
+2 010 00011122
+201000011122
00201000011122
```

I want to maintain one format in the database, however allow all my clients to use any. 
I was thinking to manipulate the model value during the validation like below:

```
   RuleFor(m => m.Phone)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(Common.ResourceFiles.Validation.Required)
            .Matches("Constants.Regex.Phone").WithMessage(Common.ResourceFiles.Validation.InvalidFormat)
            .DependentRules(d => d.RuleFor(m => m.Phone).Must(
                (model, phone) =>
                {
                    if (phone.StartsWith("+"))
                        model.Phone = model.Phone.Replace("+", "00");
                    // Other changes here
                    return true;
                }));
```

Is it legal to do so? If not what layer should enforce such a logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go down that path, it validates single responsibility principle and would be very confusing to find bugs in case your adjustments are wrong.

Instead,
You could create some kind sanitization filter, that you could easily switch on/off, and most importantly test. Your validation logic in this case would become simpler as well.

Very naive code snipped to get idea across :

```
public class ContactSanitizer
{
    public void Sanitize(ContactDto contact)
    {
        var phone = contact.Phone;

        if (phone.StartsWith("+"))
            contact.Phone = phone.Replace("+", "00");
    }
}
```